# Adding an application-wide default parameter to link_to generated links

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to alter the link_to functionality in that way, that it appends a default parameter to all links that are generated within the page.

e.g. current behavior.

```
link_to "foo", "/" generates <a href="http://www.example.com/">foo</a>
```

i want to specify in the application controller (or somewhere else central) something, that makes link_to behave like follows

```
link_to "foo", "/" generates <a href="http://www.example.com/?layout=foo">foo</a>
```

i know i could do it by adding the parameter to link_to, but i want to alter the behavior application-wide without having to edit every single link_to call.

is it possible to catch the call to link_to, append a parameter and then return the result?

current workaround i am using is to add the parameter using jquery to the href of the links.. but thats not very pretty actually

Comment: Do you need it on all the links or do you just need `params[:layout]` to be always set in your controllers?

Comment: I actually really need it on all links on the page that point to another path in the app.

Comment: actual problem is that i render the page in a specific layout when loaded in a certain iframe. i then want to stick to that layout while the user navigates in that iframe. on the other hand, when he opens the page in a new tab or window, he should see the normal layout. this is why using cookies or sessions is impossible and i had the idea to just pass the layout parameter with the links when the specific layout is needed.

Comment: How would you feel about using a custom helper instead of `link_to`?

Comment: this would mean changing the whole application :) I know that this would work, but I hoped for some kind of "unobtrusive" solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `link_to` helper method, and pass parameter of your own choice. As I have passed parameter `layout=foo` in following code.

```css
def link_to(text='',link='#',options={})
  link = link.include?('?') ? "#{link}&layout=foo" : "#{link}?layout=foo"
  super(text,link,options)
end
```